# How to Set "gas used by a transaction" value to a variable in a function?

Tags: solidity

I want to assign the gas used by transaction to a variable in function and display the output . Please let me know how to do this

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you detail where exactly you want to assign and display the gas value ? In the contract itself ( solidity ) or in your frontend ( javascript ) ?

Comment: I mean if you want to see how much gas is used by an transaction block explorers such as etherscan can do that and have apis, but it sounds like you want it to occur in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Web3 library and you want to do this on the frontend, if you're calling `sendTransaction` then the response you get back has a `receipt` object, that has a `gasUsed` key. More documentation on that is available here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

You can also use the `getTransactionReceipt` function for past transactions, as documented here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt. You'll just need to pass it the transaction hash of the past transaction. The object you get back is the same as the `receipt` key from `sendTransaction`

If you're using a different library for interacting with a node, it should have similar functions and similar responses.